# How to extract href, alt and imgsrc using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Can someone help me extract some data from the below sample html using beautiful soup python?
These are what i'm trying to extract:

The href html link : example 
    /movies/watch-malayalam-movies-online/6106-watch-buddy.html

The alt text which has the movie name : 
    Buddy 2013 Malayalam Movie

The thumbnail : example http://i44.tinypic.com/2lo14b8.jpg

(There are multiple occurrences of these..)

Full source available at : http:\\olangal.com

Sample html :

```
 <div class="item column-1">
  <h2>
   <a href="/movies/watch-malayalam-movies-online/6106-watch-buddy.html">
    Buddy
   </a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="actions">
   <li class="email-icon">
    <a href="/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=beez_20&amp;link=36bbe22fb7c54b5465609b8a2c60d8c8a1841581" title="Email" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','width=400,height=350,menubar=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">
     <img src="/media/system/images/emailButton.png" alt="Email" />
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <img width="110" height="105" alt=" Buddy 2013 Malayalam Movie" src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2lo14b8.jpg" border="0" />
  <p class="readmore">
   <a href="/movies/watch-malayalam-movies-online/6106-watch-buddy.html">
    Read more...
   </a>
  </p>
  <div class="item-separator">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item column-2">
  <h2>
   <a href="/movies/watch-malayalam-movies-online/6105-watch-pigman.html">
    Pigman
   </a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="actions">
   <li class="email-icon">
    <a href="/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=beez_20&amp;link=2b0dfb09b41b8e6fabfd7ed2a035f4d728bedb1a" title="Email" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','width=400,height=350,menubar=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">
     <img src="/media/system/images/emailButton.png" alt="Email" />
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <img width="110" height="105" alt="Pigman 2013 Malayalam Movie" src="http://i41.tinypic.com/jpa3ko.jpg" border="0" />
  <p class="readmore">
   <a href="/movies/watch-malayalam-movies-online/6105-watch-pigman.html">
    Read more...
   </a>
  </p>
  <div class="item-separator">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Update : Finally cracked it with help from @kroolik. Thanks to you.

Here's what worked for me:

```
for eachItem in soup.findAll("div", { "class":"item" }):
     eachItem.ul.decompose()

     imglinks = eachItem.find_all('img')
     for imglink in imglinks:
          imgfullLink = imglink.get('src').strip()

     links = eachItem.find_all('a')
     for link in links:
          names = link.contents[0].strip()
          fullLink = "http://olangal.com"+link.get('href').strip()
          print "Extracted : " + names + " , " + imgfullLink+" , "+fullLink
```

Comment: What have you tried before? Attribute extraction is clearly described in the BS4's documentation.

Comment: Here's what i've managed with my 1day knowledge of python and beautiful soup:
    `for eachMov in soup.findAll('img', width="110"):
         print eachMov['alt'].strip() +':'+ eachMov['src'].strip()
         print eachMov.name`  Not sure how to get the ALT text along with these

Comment: What does `eachMov['alt']` return?

Comment: eachMov['alt'] correctly returns The alt text which has the movie name : Buddy 2013 Malayalam Movie. I somehow need to get to the following <p class="read more"> and <a href=...

Comment: Do you want to get only the `<img width="110">` and `<p class="read more">` tags?

Comment: yes, i guess i can squeeze out the attributes if i can get both of these together

Answer (score 3):

You can get both `<img width="110">` and `<p class="read more">` using the following:

```
for div in soup.find_all(class_='item'):
    # Will match `<p class="readmore">...</p>` that is direct
    # child of the div.
    p = div.find(class_='readmore', recursive=False)

    # Will print `href` attribute of the first `<a>` element
    # inside `p`.
    print p.a['href']

    # Will match `<img width="110">` that is direct child
    # of the div.
    img = div.find('img', width=110, recursive=False)

    print img['src'], img['alt']
```

Note that this is for the most recent Beautiful Soup version.

Comment: I know i'm being naive, but could you also tell me how i can get the href, alt, src from the p, img ResultSet's ?

Comment: Thank you. Getting an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: @gbzygil, There was a typo that apparently has been missed. It should be fixed now.

Comment: still getting the same err :(   [I've pasted my whole code here : http://pastebin.com/FpV2yteS ]

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) for such scrapping, it's clean and easy. You can use jQuery selectors directly with it. e.g to see your Name and reputation, I will just have to write something like

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234402/gbzygil')
p=d('#user-displayname')
t=d('#user-panel-reputation div h1 a span')
print p.html()
```

So unless you can't switch from bsoup, I will strongly recommend switching to PyQuery or some library that supports XPath well.

Comment: PyQuery is not part of the existing setup. BeautifulSoup is. Don't have the permission to install new...